# Factoring $({16+4t^2+\frac{t^4}{4}})^{1/4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you go about factoring $({16+4t^2+\frac{t^4}{4}})^{1/4}$
Which factoring method would be the best?

Comment: I would suggest factoring the inside first.  Perhaps you could try writing $s=t^2$ and using the quadratic formula (or something similar).

Comment: Do you want the answer factored or simplified?

Comment: factored then simplified.

Comment: Recognize that the parenthesized term is a square.

Comment: Which factorisation methods do you know?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $t^4/4 = (t^2/2)^2$ so let $u = t^2/2$

Then $({16+4t^2+\frac{t^4}{4}})^{1/4} = (16 + 8u + u^2)^{1/4}$

$16 + 8u + u^2 = (4+u)^2$ and $(a^2)^{1/4} = a^{1/2}$

So $({16+4t^2+\frac{t^4}{4}})^{1/4} = (16 + 8u + u^2)^{1/4} = (4 +u)^{1/2} = (4+t^2/2)^{1/2}$

Is that simplified enough?

Comment: In the finish of answer you must replace $u=t^2/2$

Comment: Didn't I?  Oh, oops.  I put the wrong variable back.  I'll fix this.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left({16+4t^2+\frac{t^4}{4}}\right)^{1/4}=\left({4^2+2\cdot4\cdot\frac{t^2}{2}+\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)^2}\right)^{1/4}=$$
$$=\left(\left(4+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)^2\right)^{1/4}=\left(4+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)^{2\cdot{1/4}}=\left(4+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)^{{1/2}}$$